# Troubleshooting - How to enabled TLS 1.2 on Windows 2008 Server SP2

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, tls1.2

There is a Windows Server 2008 SP2 (source) which connects to a cloud application (destination).
The destination is to disable TLS v1.0 and v1.1, and we tried to enable TLS v1.2 on the source side.

The Windows server 2008 SP2 has .Net 4.0 and .Net application connects to the destination from the source.

What we have tried:

1. Create registry keys with following the below reference
   https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx
2. Add `runtime` tag in the configuration file for the .Net application before `</configuration>`

   ```
   <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSystemDefaultTlsVersions=false"/>
   ```

When the destination disabled TLS v1.0 an V1.1, the .Net application fails with "
Error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". When older versions are roll-backed, it runs successfully.

Could anyone please advise what is missing? Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need a hotfix to add TLS 1.2 support and you cannot follow any Windows Server 2008 R2 articles (that's a different OS release). However, Windows Server 2008 is end-of-life, so Microsoft removed all relevant information/downloads from its own sites. Overall, your only feasible option today is to upgrade to Windows Server 2012 and above.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your comment. We found these 3 Kbs need to be applied.
• KB3080079
• KB3140245
• KB4019276
We are in the process of migration to newer OS but it will not be able to be completed by the time destination application disable TLS v1.0 and v1.1. This is until the migration is done.